# Java constructor arguments not matching

Tags: java, constructor

Why is jGrasp not recognizing that my constructor needs two doubles? Especially, since I have only the one constructor.

This is my class:

```
public class SavingsAccount{
   private double balance;
   private double interestRate;
   private double lastInterest;

   public void SavingsAccount(double bal, double intRate){

      balance = bal;
      interestRate = intRate;
   }

//Other methods

}
```

And in my main method, I try instantiating it like so:

```
double bal = 500.00;
double intRate = .002;
SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(bal, intRate);
```

But when I try to run this is jGrasp, it shows me an error that read

```
TestSavingsAccount.java:9: error: constructor SavingsAccount in class SavingsAccount cannot be applied to given types;
  SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount(bal, intRate);
                           ^
required: no arguments
found: double,double
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Answer (score 3):

Your "constructor" has a `void` word which makes it a method. Constructor cannot have a return type. You need to remove it:

```
public SavingsAccount(double bal, double intRate){

      balance = bal;
      interestRate = intRate;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     public void SavingsAccount(double bal, double intRate){
      balance = bal;
      interestRate = intRate;
     }
```

Should be:

```
     public SavingsAccount(double bal, double intRate){
      balance = bal;
      interestRate = intRate;
     }
```

You declared a method with adding void to the signature.